# TeXShop 4.27 preferences panel doesn't have Theme tab

Tags: texshop

I installed MacTeX-2019 distribution and, as the title says, I  don't have the Theme tab in the preferences panel of TeXShop which allows me to change the source page colours. Moreover, the "OK" button doesn't close the preferences panel once I click it.

[image]

Comment: What OS version are you using? Are you sure you’re using TeXShop 4.27 since the Preference Panel you Show is from an older version of TeXSop?

Comment: The OS is 10.14 and the TeXShop version was indeed 4.27

Answer (score 1):

I ended up downloading just TeXShop from the University of Oregon website and I replaced the application. This fixed the problem and now the preferences panel works correctly and has the Themes tab. I thought that maybe there was a problem in the TeXShop provided by MacTeX.

Comment: Do you have more than one version of TeXShop on your system?

Comment: No, I had only the 4.27 version that I installed through the MacTeX 2019 distribution.